# Pass variables from AS3 swf to AS2 swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I am trying to load an AS2 swf from an AS3 swf. The AS2 swf which was written long back, expects parameters from the timeline(_root). These were passed to it before from HTML using flashvars.

Now I am trying to get rid of the HTML pages, by directly loading the AS2 swf from the AS3 swf. However, when I try to load the AS2 swf using the Loader class, the swf loads fine, but the parameters are not getting passed on.

I tried to add the query string to the url parameter I used in the URL request used for the Loader, but that did not work.(Adding URL variables as data to URLRequest did not work either.)Is there any way that I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Loader.contentLoaderInfo.parameters` ?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the AVM1Movie docs:

```
...no interoperability (such as calling methods or using parameters) 
between the AVM1Movie object and AVM2 objects is allowed.
```